Change the status text in a cell (e.g. from Ongoing to Alert), if the date on another cell passes 30 days
I have received date on column B and status on column A (Ongoing, Closed, Alert, Waiting to receive the product, Not started).
How can i change the status of column A(for example from ongoing to alert) if it has gone more than 30 days from the column B?

Not changing status even though i formatted the date

You need to have this IF() within your "status" checking:
A1: =IF(B1-TODAY()>30,"alert","")
Dates in any spreadsheet (as excel) are a day count from a base date,
with a decimal part telling how large portion of of 24 hours has passed since midnight.
Base date: Enter 1 in a cell and format it as Date (CTRL+1).
